# feedback needed for my first python tkinter simple MVC, list element to print to label

Tags: python, python-3.x, mvc, tkinter

Just starting to get the idea of MVC with tkinter. I wrote this simple program and I'm looking for feedback. There are no errors, but I don't know if I set it up right or not.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Model():

    def __init__(self):
      self.list = ["email", "sms", 'voice']

class View(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="yellow", bd=2, 
           relief=tk.RIDGE)
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack()

        self.labelVariable=tk.StringVar()
        self.output=tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable, 
             bg="orange", fg="white")
        self.output.pack()

        self.hello = tk.Button(self, text="Show", command= 
             self.controller.hello_Button_Pressed,  bd=2,            
             relief=tk.RIDGE)
        self.hello.pack(side="left")


class Controller():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.model = Model()
        self.view = View(self.root, self)

        self.root.title("MVC example")
        self.root.geometry("250x350")
        self.root.config(background="LightBlue4")
        self.root.mainloop()

    def hello_Button_Pressed(self):
        self.view.labelVariable.set(self.model.list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Controller()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Can you tell us more about what the code is supposed to do? Does the code have a purpose? I understand you want to learn about MVC, that's your goal. What's the goal of the *code*?

Comment: Hi @Mast, thanks for responding.  This code is just to print the list onto the label.  Nothing else.  I could do this code without MVC, but to elevate my learning, i wanted to organize it with MVC.  If this is correct, without much feedback, I will begin to rewrite most of my other programs into MVC, so any thoughts are welcomed. thanks again.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add the purpose of the code there. In the comment it is not visible enough.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks like it is set up fine for MVC. I'm not an expert but I have enogh experience to tell that it's fine.

Comment: thanks @Cruise Lickerman.  it took me a while to understand the set up of MVC, and now I can start use it.

Comment: Yeah took me a while also